# Doctrine: GROUP BY HAVING

Tags: doctrine

I'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT 
     userId, count(userId) as counter 
 FROM 
     quicklink 
 GROUP BY 
     userId 
 HAVING 
     count(*) >= 3'
```

In doctrine with the querybuilder, I've got this:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->select('userId, count(userId) as counter')
            ->groupby('userId')
            ->having('counter >= 3')
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
```

Which gives me this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 103 near 'HAVING count(*)': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification variable.
```

Really struggling with doctrine. :(

Comment: I think it's complaining that `count(*)` is not `count(UserId)`

Comment: `count(*)` is not an identifier. You should use your alias `counter`.

Answer (score 9):

Your SQL is **valid**, Your query builder statement is **invalid**

All cause db will execute that query in following order:

```
 1. FROM      $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
 2. GROUP BY  ->groupby('userId') // GROUP BY
 3. HAVING    ->having('counter >= 3')
 4. SELECT    ->select('userId, count(userId) as counter')
```

So as You can see `counter` is defined **after** its use in having.

Its SQL Quirk. You **can not** use definitions from select in `where` or `having` statements.

So correct code:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->select('userId, count(userId) as counter')
            ->groupby('userId')
            ->having('count(userId) >= 3')
            ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

Do note repetition in `having` from `select`

Answer (score 2):

I am going to answer for people who still have this type of error.

First things first, you seem to have translated a native sql query inside a query builder object. More so, you have named your object as **q**

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');
```

What this means, in general, is that every condition or grouping etc you have in your logic should address fields of **q**: `q.userId, q.gender, ...`

So, if you had written your code like below, you would have avoided your error:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->select('q.userId, count(q.userId) as counter')
            ->groupby('q.userId')
            ->having('counter >= 3')
            ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the 'from' statement

Comment: `createQueryBuilder`, called inside a repository, doesn't need a root entity declaration (aka FROM). The root entity is the repository's related entity.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "t, count(t.userId) as counter FROM YourBundle:Table t group by t.userId having counter >1 ";
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($query)->getResult();
```

This should work. You can even do left joins or apply where clausules.

Answer (score 0):

you can define HAVING parameter via setParameter() method as well

```
 $qb->groupBy('userId');
 $qb->having('COUNT(*) = :some_count');
 $qb->setParameter('some_count', 3);
```