# Use the Doctrine's QueryBuilder to get Categories with a minimum number of products

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4, query-builder

I want to use the Doctrine's QueryBuilder to get Categories with a specified attribute and a number minimum of products inside. I precise that's the first time I use this Doctrine's function. I discovered that and I realized that it's so much powerful than basics repositories functions. I'm a very beginner with SQL because I used to use Repository's functions.

But I think I achieve this in pure SQL:

```
SELECT category.*,COUNT(*)
FROM category_product 
INNER JOIN category ON category_product.category_id = category.id 
WHERE category.name = 'region' 
GROUP BY category_product.category_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 20
```

At the moment I'm totally lost with DQL construction. My Category and Product Entities both have a Many to Many relationship and I can't reach traducing this to Doctrine. I tried using the category_product table auto-generated by doctrine's but It doesn't want to access this table...

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

        $qb
            ->select('c')
            ->where("c.name = 'region'")
            ->innerJoin('c.products', 'p', 'WITH', 'COUNT(c.products) > :minimum')
            ->setParameter('minimum', $minimum);

        dump($qb->getQuery(), $qb->getQuery()->getResult());
```

Each Time I uses a new construction I have Semantical errors I'm not able to correct...

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could try some thing like here (piece of code from my working model)

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.name = region')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(c.products) AS counter')
        ->innerJoin('c.products', 'p')
        ->groupby('p.id')
        ->having('count(p.id) >= :minimum')
        ->setParameter('region', $region)
        ->setParameter('minimum', $minimum)
      ;

    dump($qb->getQuery()->getResult());
```

related post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061128/doctrine-group-by-having)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Theva ! But I stuck on this error: 
 Error: Expected Literal, got 'count'...

However I haven't used double quotes...

Comment: May be replace 'count' by another name 'total'

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 118 near 'total > :min': Error: 'total' is not defined.

            ->addSelect('COUNT(c.products) AS total')
            ->innerJoin('c.products', 'p')
            ->having('total > :minimum')

I changed like this

Comment: we have missed groupeby clause, I have edited the answer and let you try out

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks to you I got it.

I shouldn't select the COUNT because I typed the return to be an Array of categories but it returned an array of arrays with contains the category and the count... I had to group by c too.

Thanks a lot for your help !

The answer is :

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c')
            ->where('c.name = :region')
            ->innerJoin('c.products', 'p')
            ->groupBy('c')
            ->having('SIZE(c.products) > :minimum')
            ->setParameter('region', $region)
            ->setParameter('minimum', 20);
```